# Convert a Dictionary to an Interface

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a Dictionary in to an impmentation of an Interface.

I can get a Dictionary to an Object okay.  Doing something like this:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this IDictionary<string, object> source)
    where T : class, new()
    {
        var someObject = new T();
        var someObjectType = someObject.GetType();

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            someObjectType.GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(someObject, item.Value, null);
        }

        return someObject;
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, object> AsDictionary(this object source, BindingFlags bindingAttr = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        return source.GetType().GetProperties(bindingAttr).ToDictionary
        (
            propInfo => propInfo.Name,
            propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(source, null)
        );

    }
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Prop1", "hello world!"}, {"Prop2", 3893}};
var someObject = dictionary.ToObject<A>();
```

But I want to be able to:

```
var someObject = dictionary.ToObject<iA>();
```

Anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: It looked terrible for me to write an extension method of `object` without a good reason.

Comment: Are you actually just trying to do serialization? If so, there are much easier ways. E.g. look up DataContractSerializer for XML or Json.NET for JSON.

Comment: If you're trying to develop this for unit testing, you may want to consider using an existing mocking framework like Moq.  These frameworks already have support for creating classes on the fly that implement an interface and you could easily create a helper method that convert a Dictionary to a series of Moq Setup calls.

Comment: Only Chuck Norris can instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a concrete implementation of that interface. You could do this by using the [TypeBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx).

Alternatively you could use a dynamic type and [Impromptu](https://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/)

```
using ImpromptuInterface;
using ImpromptuInterface.Dynamic;

public interface IMyInterface
{
   string Prop1 { get;  }
}

//Anonymous Class
var anon = new {
         Prop1 = "Test",
}

var myInterface = anon.ActLike<IMyInterface>();
```

I like Amy's solution a lot better though. Both of the above are much more complex, however they can be done without forcing the caller to specify the actual concrete type.

Comment: I don't know if Castle DynamicProxy (http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) could fit exactly but I've used it for similar use-cases, like mixins.